# добавления новой ячейки по index.row == 0?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Подскажите, у меня три массива и для каждого свой сегмент контроль. В какой функции нужно указывать какие объекты добавляются и как происходит добавление новой ячейки?

Первый вариант :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
    }
}
```

второй вариант :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
}
```

Comment: Расшифруйте пожалуйста "подскажите у меня три массива и для каждого свой сегмент контроль".
В функции cellForRowAt вы указываете как именно создается ячейка.

Answer (score 0):

Можно объединить эти 3 массива в один.

Допустим вот ваши 3 массива.

```
let sectionOne = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
let sectionTwo = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
let sectionThree = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

Можно добавить новое свойство

```
var mainArray: [[String]] = []
```

В методе `viewDidLoad()`

Добавить ваши массивы в общий

```
mainArray = [sectionOne, sectionTwo, sectionThree]
```

После чего реализовать методы `UITableViewDataSource`

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return mainArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return mainArray[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let dataForCell = mainArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    //dataForCell - строка которую надо выводить в ячейке
    }
```

Comment: Это я знаю, я имел виду как сделать чтоб все время при добавлении нового объекта с сервера, он в ячейки первым был, а не последним

Comment: просто переворачивайте массив при добавлении объекта.